# Repeated log messages hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using java swing + hibernate. Not sure how to use hibernate with swing.

Following is my persistence,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
<persistence-unit name="mypu">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.example.Student</class>
   <!-- there are more entities -->

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Not sure I am doing write or not. I have DAO calss for each entity class and it looks like

```
class StudentDAO {
  private EntityManagerFactory emf;
  private EntityManager em;

  public StudentDAO()
  {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mypu");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
  }
}
```

So each DAO class has above code.

When I run project **It shows following message about 8-10 times in console.**
Thats why it taking time to run project.

> > Jun 26, 2016 9:46:13 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
> >     configure
> >
> > WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!) Jun 26, 2016 9:46:13 AM
> >     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
> >     buildCreator
> >
> > INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb] Jun 26, 2016 9:46:13 AM
> >     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
> >     buildCreator
> >
> > INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****} Jun 26, 2016 9:46:13 AM
> >     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
> >     buildCreator
> >
> > INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false Jun 26, 2016 9:46:13 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
> >     configure
> >
> > INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1) Jun 26, 2016 9:46:13 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  INFO: HHH000400:
> >     Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect Jun 26, 2016
> >     9:46:13 AM  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
> >
> > INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory Jun 26, 2016 9:46:13 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator validate INFO:
> >     HHH000229: Running schema validator Jun 26, 2016 9:46:13 AM
> >     org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator validate INFO: HHH000102:
> >     Fetching database metadata Jun 26, 2016 9:46:13 AM
> >     org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata
> >
> > INFO: HHH000261: Table found: mydb.student Jun 26, 2016 9:46:13 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  INFO: HHH000037:
> >     Columns: [id, name, address]
> >     org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry
> >     addEntityManagerFactory
> >
> > WARN: HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (mypu) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated,
> >     specify a unique value for property
> >     'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name' Jun 26, 2016 9:46:13 AM
> >     org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
> >
> > WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
> >     [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use
> >     [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead. Jun 26, 2016
> >     9:46:13 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
> >
> > WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
> >     [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use
> >     [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead. Jun 26, 2016
> >     9:46:13 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
> >
> > WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
> >     [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use
> >     [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead. Jun 26, 2016
> >     9:46:13 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper
> >     logPersistenceUnitInformation INFO: HHH000204: Processing
> >     PersistenceUnitInfo [     name: mypu

**Why it is showing above message so many times?**
Thank you for help !!

Comment: are you getting any `Exception` ? they are just warning you can ignore

Comment: no exceptions...but its taking time to run executable jar and thats the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each DAO you are creating a new EntityManagerFactory. You should not create new EntityManagerFactory for each of your request or worse for each operation. So at first try to created only one EntityManagerFactory for you app and use that in each operation . The reason being creation of EntityManagerFactory is expensive.

The logs that you see are displayed when an entity manager factory is created .. it is showing you the process of the emf creation. If you create emf once you will get that logs only once.

Please make sure that you create and use only one EntityManagerFactory .. you app will start working fast.

PFB the below link for some more details

[How frequently should I create an EntityManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225638/how-frequently-should-i-create-an-entitymanager)